# How to format the first X rows based on sort order?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that calculates a score for each row based on numeric values in the different columns. I then sort it by the calculated score, high to low. Now I want to conditionally format (bold) the first X rows in the sheet based on that sort order.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve that? I've been googling for hours now, but no joy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
=rows(A$1:A1)<=10
```

for first 10 rows

Comment: Thanks Tom! It wasn't 100% correct, but close enough to get me there. :-)

The right solution is conditional formatting with a custom formula `=ROW($A1)<=X`.